# Picking an arbitrary element from an equivalence class

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I want to define a function $f$ over a quotient set $E/R$. The trouble is that I want to say $f([M]_R) = g(M')$ for some $M'\in[M]_R$ and $g$ a certain previously well-defined function.

Any member of the equivalence class $[M]_R$ would do, but how do I pick one?

The bigger picture here is that I want prove that said function $f$ exists and is unique. The remaining properties I need to check are verified by $g$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would probably help if you wrote what everything really is. As currently stated, there is no reason why $f$ should be well-defined, and you have not mentioned what properties you want it to be unique with respect to.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I could do so, but the definitions are long and I thought it would not matter since the question is on how to pick an element of an equivalence class.

Comment: But that is not really the question, since you are claiming that the choice will not matter. So are you simply asking why you are allowed to pick an element?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I think you are right, perhaps that is what I should have asked.

Comment: You need to ask this. If $xRy$, is $g(x)= g(y)$?